# How to get RSSI value from Veins framework?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I came across some code to get `RSSI` from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562956/how-to-record-rssi-in-veins-omnet) on stackoverflow.
However, only some code is presented, so I wrote the code as follows to check the result. However, it is questionable whether or not this has normally obtained `RSSI`.

RSU.h

```
...
#include "veins/modules/phy/DeciderResult80211.h"
#include "veins/base/phyLayer/PhyToMacControlInfo.h"
```

RSU.cc

```
// If received some message from other node
double rssi = check_and_cast<DeciderResult80211*>(check_and_cast<PhyToMacControlInfo*>(wsm -> getControlInfo()) -> getDeciderResult()) -> getRecvPower_dBm();
EV << "RSSI Value: " << rssi << std::endl;
...
```

Comment: What experiments did you already perform to check your hypothesis? In what way did the result not match your expectations?

Comment: @ChristophSommer Some values are displayed normally when outputting the `EV`. For example, `-53.8234`. However, I'm wondering if this is the `RSSI` value calculated by the `RSSI` formula.