# Locate a vehicle using RSSI under veins framework

Tags: omnet++, veins

Using the veins framework and the Omnet++ simulator, how do I get the RSSI value (RSU side) from the message sent from a vehicle? I need to locate this vehicle using this RSSI value.

How to send multiple messages from the same vehicle simultaneously? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How do I get the RSSI value (RSU side) from the message sent from a vehicle?
   Answer: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594801/7215379
   has a similar Q & A.
2. How to send multiple messages from the same vehicle simultaneously?
   Answer: Are you talking about sending multiple copies of the same message or sending message of different type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am talking about sending several messages of different types.Well precisely the same type of message with different data. (I want to simulate Sybil Attack).

Comment: Please have a look at tic toc example. It's shows (I guess  example 3) how to add a counter which is incremented every time you send a message.

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it's relevant